# Como crear una copia de otra tabla en Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen dia.

Tengo dos bases de datos, lo que necesito es crear en la base de datos destino una tabla que sea igual a la tabla de la base de datos origen. Solo necesito la estructura de la tabla.

Probé con lo sigueiente:

```
SELECT * Into BDestino.Tablanueva 
From BOrigen.tabla1 
Where 1 = 2
```

Copia toda la estructura pero no copia la primary key ni tampoco en caso que tenga algun otro constraint. Tampoco si alguna es identity.

¿Como se podria crear una tabla a partir de otra?

Comment: En el Management hay una opción que se llama "Generar Script",  hace una copia tal cual de la base de datos o tabla (Según elijas) en la que puedes incluso definir si copiar los registros o no. Saludos! ^^

Comment: Si, pero lo que necesito es para crear dentro de un sp pasando la base de datos origen y la base de datos destino y poder crear igual

Comment: No se si te entiendo bien, pero podrías usar un "use db" para comunicar tus Bases de Datos. ¿Necesitas copiar solamente una tabla con su estructura, no?

Comment: Lo que necesito es crear una procedimiento almacenado donde paso  como parametros una base de datos orgen y otra destino. Tengo que comparar ambas bases de datos y por ejemplo si la Base de datos origen tiene una tabla que no tenga la base de datos destino tengo que crearla tal cual esta en la base de datos origen en la base de datos destino

Comment: Vale, ahora si te entendí, ya te ayudo con el SP.

Comment: Que tantas diferencias quieres cubrir? Sólo crear objetos inexistentes o también corregir diferencias como agregar columnas?

Comment: En este caso solo crear la tabla inexistente, despues con eso seguramente se me ocurrira como corregir las diferencias.

Comment: Te dejo un script creado por un conocido. Ha trabajado durante mucho tiempo en esto y lo ha ido mejorando poco a poco. http://www.stormrage.com/SQLStuff/sp_GetDDL_Latest.txt

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo haciendo un select todo de tu tablas
ejemplo:

```
Select * into nueva_table  from vieja_table
```

esto creara una copia exacta de la vieja_tabla

## referencia:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15